# How can I get a URL to the recipient view of an existing envelope using the DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I've looked through the documentation but haven't been able to find a way to do this. What I'm currently doing is storing envelope IDs along with their expiration date in a database, so I want to be able to show the user the same envelope if they have one already open. However I don't know how to retrieve this URL after the creation of the envelope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it, you will need to `POST` by using the `createRecipient` method. More information can be found here.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient